# Open set in a subspace topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $C=\{1/n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, on $\mathbb{R}$ we have the standard topology.

> **Question.** Why the one-point set $\{1/n\}$ are all open in $C$ with the subspace topology?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$O$ is open in $C$

$ \iff$ there is an open $U$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $O = U \cap C$.

Choose an interval $(1/n-\epsilon , 1/n +\epsilon)$, open in $\mathbb{R}$ with $\epsilon$ small enough s.t.

$ C \cap (1/n-\epsilon, 1/n+\epsilon)=${$1/n$}.

$...1/(n+1), 1/n, 1/(n-1),...$

$1/n-1/(n+1)= \dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}$;

$1/(n-1)-1/n= \dfrac{1}{n(n-1)} >$

$\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}$.

Choose for example $\epsilon =\dfrac{1}{2n(n+1)}$.

Answer (score 3):

Because the intervall $$\left(\frac{1}{n}- \frac{1}{2n(n+1)}, \frac{1}{n}+ \frac{1}{2n(n+1)}\right)$$

is open, contains $\frac{1}{n}$, but does not contain any other point of $C$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Shouldn't we write $1/n$ as $C\cap V$, where $V$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes. Actually, what I say in my answer is equivalent to say that $\lbrace 1/n \rbrace = C \cap V$, where $V$ is the open intervall I constructed.

Answer (score 2):

A subset $V$ of $C$ is open in the subspace topology of $\mathbf R$ if $V = C\cap U$ for some open set $U$ in $\mathbf R$. So we are saying that the one-point sets $V=\{1\},\{1/2\},\{1/3\},\dots$ each can be written as $C\cap U_1$, $C\cap U_2$, $C\cap U_3$, and so on, for open sets $U_1,U_2,U_3,\ldots\subset\mathbf R$. Can you draw a picture to figure out what the sets $U_1,U_2,U_3,\dots$ could be?